# SQL Server pivot with "ties"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my source data:

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+
| Categ | Nm    | Value | Rnk  |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
| A     | Tom   |    37 |    1 |
| A     | Joe   |    36 |    2 |
| A     | Eddie |    35 |    3 |
| B     | Seth  |    28 |    1 |
| B     | Ed    |    25 |    2 |
| B     | Billy |    22 |    3 |
| C     | Julie |    42 |    1 |
| C     | Jenny |    41 |    2 |
| C     | April |    40 |    3 |
| C     | Mary  |    40 |    3 |
| C     | Laura |    40 |    3 |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

And here is the output I would like to produce:

```
+------+--------+--------+-------+
| Rnk  |   A    |   B    |   C   |
+------+--------+--------+-------+
|    1 | Tom    | Seth   | Julie |
|    2 | Joe    | Ed     | Jenny |
|    3 | Eddie  | Billy  | April |
|    3 | (null) | (null) | Mary  |
|    3 | (null) | (null) | Laura |
+------+--------+--------+-------+
```

I have used the following approach (which I understand through other posts may be superior to actually using PIVOT)...and this gets me to where I see Julie/Jenny/April, but not Mary/Laura (obviously, since it is pulling the MIN in the event of a 'tie').

```
SELECT Rnk
, min(CASE WHEN Categ = 'A' THEN Nm END) as A
, min(CASE WHEN Categ = 'B' THEN Nm END) as B
, min(CASE WHEN Categ = 'C' THEN Nm END) as C
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY Rnk
```

How to get to my desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want multiple rows for each rank, you can't aggregate by rank, or at least by rank alone.  So, calculate the rank-within-the-rank or as the following query calls it, the `sub_rnk`:

```
SELECT Rnk,
       min(CASE WHEN Categ = 'A' THEN Nm END) as A,
       min(CASE WHEN Categ = 'B' THEN Nm END) as B,
       min(CASE WHEN Categ = 'C' THEN Nm END) as C
FROM (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by categ, rnk order by newid()) as sub_rnk
      from Tbl t
     ) t
GROUP BY rnk, sub_rnk
ORDER BY rnk;
```